# How to write text right-to-left on an image using freetype package in go?

Tags: image, go, freetype

I'm trying to type some Arabic text on an image.
How can I do it without reversing the string?

Comment: The code looks like everything lays out from left to right.  What is the problem with reversing the string? You might want to make use of [https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/unicode/bidi](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/unicode/bidi)

Comment: Reversing the string for RTL text is not trivial once numbers, mixed alphabets, text wrapping and really anything more than a word or two is laid out. I would strongly suggest that if the bidi library doesn't work, to only attempt reveral as a manual intervention or for very constrained inputs, otherwise before long you will produce results that are not very legible. As a hebrew speaker, there used to be a lot of hebrew out there that I could only read because I'm also a programmer. Thankfully that's less common nowadays.

Comment: @matt.s Thanks, but that's just a bunch of function signatures you liked me. unfortunately nothing is implemented yet in that package.

Comment: @Eternal_ink, sorry. I had assumed that the sub repo would work. My bad.

Comment: @matt.s no problem I'm gonna dig this one https://github.com/01walid/goarabic